# Is a Warlock's Curse damage Psychic?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock

Does the damage from the Warlocks class feature `Warlock's Curse` get the `Psychic`?

... we've just had a combat and the monsters have `Vulnerability Psychic`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**  <sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=Class&id=7)]</sup>

The warlock's curse damage is untyped ... *like the extra damage for most other strikers*

Comment: Someone always beats me to the answer =P

Comment: @TheJug I'm fast, but I have to grab compendium links from my phone so not always good quotes :P

Answer (score 9):

**No, unless you use mindbite scorn**

If you're a sorcerer-king warlock with the feat [mindbite scorn](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3227), you get:

> Your Warlock’s Curse extra damage increases by 1d6, and this additional damage is psychic.

Answer (score 4):

The Warlock curse is a class feature that merely adds extra damage when you attack. As stated in the feature on page 131 of the PHB

```
A cursed enemy is more vulnerable to your attacks. 
If you damage a cursed enemy, you deal extra damage.
```

There is no type to it, it's just extra damage.

Comment: So it increases the damage of the source that triggers it, and thus the extra damage is of the same type, right?